# How to reload modules after modifying php files in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm a newbie using magento 2, and i'm trying to modify a custom module (MercadoPago), i'm modifying the PHP file i need to modify but when I reload the page it doesn't seem to work.

I tried the same thing with a Hello world module, modifying its php files and the changes are still not made when i reload the page.

I tried using

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

But doesn't work. How can i make my changes goes live on my site? I don't want to create a new module to replace the existing one neither want to change the version, i just want to modify some few lines of code.

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your system on developer mode:
 - If you are using magento 2.0.x and 2.1.x -  clear **root/var/generated/** folder contents
 - If you are using Magento 2.2.x - clear **root/generated/** folder contents

If you are running it on the production mode:
 - rm -rf generated/*; php bin/magento setup:di:compile; php bin/magento cache:clean;

Kind suggest, before working on something huge like Magento 2 - read basics - what is deployment modes, how they are working, some basic rules (technical guidelines) and etc.

More over I suggeest to extend module using either a **dependency injection** or **plugins**. That would save you from **changes loss** when module is updated.

Comment: Thank you so much, i'm aware of the risks of modifying the module itself instead of creating a new one that replaces the templates